# Parsing XML data within tags using lxml in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml.etree

My question is regarding how to get information stored in a tag which allows for no closing tag. Here's the relevant xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<uws:job>  
<uws:results>
    <uws:result id="2014-03-03T15:42:31:1337" xlink:href="http://www.cosmosim.org/query/index/stream/table/2014-03-03T15%3A42%3A31%3A1337/format/csv" xlink:type="simple"/>
</uws:results>
</uws:job>
```

I'm looking to extract the xlink:href url here. As you can see the uws:result tag requires no closing tag. Additionally, having the 'uws:' makes it a bit tricky to handle them when working in python. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(xmlresponse.content)
url = root.find('{*}results').text
```

Where xmlresponse.content is the xml data to be parsed. What this returns is

```
'\n    '
```

which indicates that it's only finding the newline character, since what I'm really after is contained within a tag inside the results tag. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide the first xml declaration line of the xml.

Comment: Added the declaration statement.

Answer (score 2):

You found the right node; you extracted the data incorrectly. Instead of

```
url = root.find('{*}results').text
```

you really want

```
url = root.find('{*}results').get('attribname', 'value_to_return_if_not_present')
```

or

```
url = root.find('{*}results').attrib['attribname']
```

(which will throw an exception if not present).

Because of the namespace on the attribute itself, you will probably need to use the `{ns}attrib` syntax to look it up too.

You can dump out the attrib dictionary and just copy the attribute name out too.

`text` is actually the space *between* elements, and is not normally used but is supported both for spacing (like etreeindent) and some special cases.